# How to record audio in a mobile browser?

Tags: ios, html, mobile, audio, webrtc

I would like to record audio in the browser on iOS and Android.
What are my options right now (oct. 2013) ?

How fast is WebRTC being adopted from the different browser makers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MediaStream Recording API is implemented in Firefox Beta on Android, but not yet in Chrome (though their is an [Intent to Implement](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/2l_G_apqk30)).

[simpl.info/mediarecorder](http://simpl.info/mediarecorder)

You can also try recorder.js with Web Audio: [http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html](http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/input).